How can I paste images in Confluence when pasting fails with error 'The server is not responding. Please check it is running'?
I am on Windows 10. I say this in advance since it became clear later that the problem here is not Confluence, but Windows, and still, it should stay here on Web Applications SE since the error happens in Confluence, not on Windows.
When trying to paste an image file/attachment in Confluence, it sometimes returns an error and the operation fails.  When this happens, updating and reopening/refreshing the Confluence site doesn't resolve the situation.
When I've encountered this issue, I have pasted screenshots of the images instead of the attachments themselves, but that isn't a great workaround and I'm looking for a better solution.
Error message roughly translated from German:

The server is not responding. Please check it is running.

Actual German error:

Der Server antwortet nicht. Bitte überprüfen Sie, ob er läuft.


How can I paste images in Confluence when pasting fails with error 'The server is not responding. Please check it is running'?

Meta noise:
I keep the old answer with the bad workaround alive, which abides to the rules of Stack Exchange, when two answers are a clear split which need their own votes and standing.

I later found out that the workaround of the first answer is not needed if you shrink down the length of the path to < 260 characters, without the filename at the end. Mind that the length is not just what you see as the path but also the name technical server or technical Active Directory or anything else that Windows needs to reach the file. For example, a path length of more than 211 characters is enough to throw the Confluence error in question.
I found out about this only after a long time of pasting images in Confluence, only in times running into this error, never knowing what was going on. But it is that easy: I often sort screenshots into new subfolders on another server's Active Directory (ad-...) path and name the subfolders by what the sample of screenshots is about. Then it depends on the folder tree and length of the new folder name to reach 211 (or on your system something up to 260) characters. Since these folders are so scattered and the path length not clear from the last level I did not run into this, even if the answer seems so easy once you know about it.
See my learning path at Why have all photos of some folders turned black in any application but show up when copied to places higher up in the tree or other devices?. This only brought up the idea of the answer here, and I checked it in Confluence right away.

The workaround is to make a full copy of the images. Then, you can copy and paste the new images to Confluence.
That means, do not just copy them to the clipboard, but make a second file of them:

either in the same folder which will rename them as a copy,
or if you do not want the renaming, copy them to another folder.

It is not enough to copy the folder that the images are in, you need to copy the files themselves.
After that, remove either the old or the new images.
